# Hyperspectral Detection of Ore

Tags: mineralogy, minerals

How can I use hyperspectral satellite imagery to remotely detect copper or any prespecified mineral deposit in general?

Where can I find a database of the absorption and reflection bands of various ores, and what satellite imagery source could give reliable data?

Comment: This should get you started: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=hyperspectral%20exploration%20ore%20deposits&btnG=Search&as_sdt=800000000001&as_sdtp=on

Answer (score 1):

Hyperspectral analysis is being used in mining and exploration extensively as a cheaper and quicker alternative to the likes of x-ray fluorescence, x-ray diffraction and others. Hyperspectral is even being used on an active mining faces with scanners installed on excavators and processed image being fed to a computer display that operator can use to direct digging of ores.

Now, as to the crux of your question - no, or at least very difficult. The problem with hyperspectral for ranged resource detection is that it primarily uses visual and near-infrared parts of spectrum. These wavelengths are very easily absorbed/scattered by everything and, therefore, they lack any penetration.

In most cases Earth's surface on satellite imagery will be covered by vegetation and various recent sedimentary formations which will make it nigh impossible to 'see' the bedrock potentially containing ore-bearing rock types and mineralogies.